# Null object reference JAVA

Tags: java, android

O problema todo esta acontecendo em uma pesquisa, quando clico e começo a digitar o campo ele vai filtrando os resultados, quando clico em um destes resultados para abrir outra tela, da este erro:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

O código da pesquisa esta assim:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_restaurante, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    searchView = null;
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        if(restaurantes == null || restaurantes.size() == 0){
            searchView.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                filtrarRestaurante(arg0);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    //searchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

A função `filtarRestaurante(agr0)` é esta:

```
public void filtrarRestaurante(String filtro){
 ArrayList<Restaurante> restaurantesEncontrados = new ArrayList<Restaurante>();

    if(filtro.length() == 0 && restaurantes != null){
        restaurantes.clear();
        restaurantes.addAll(restaurantesBkp);
        configurarAdapter();
        return;
    }

    // Procura pelo restaurante
    restaurantes.clear();
    restaurantes.addAll(restaurantesBkp);
    for(Restaurante restaurante : restaurantes){
        if(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante().toLowerCase().contains(filtro.toLowerCase())){
            restaurantesEncontrados.add(restaurante);
        }
    }
    restaurantes = restaurantesEncontrados;
    configurarAdapter();
}
```

Aqui é o init da meu fragment:

```
    @AfterViews
public void init() {
    Globales.setPedido(new Pedido());

    restaurante = (Restaurante) getArguments().getSerializable(RESTAURANTE_CARDAPIO);
    Globales.setRestauranteAtual(restaurante);
    carregarCardapio(restaurante);
}
```

Assim eu instancio o restaurante:

```
Restaurante restaurante;
```

Este erro esta acontecendo quando clico no restaurante e o erro acontece aqui:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
        updateCarrinho();
        Globales.setListaOpcionais(null);

        TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbarTitle.setText(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante());
    }catch (Exception e){
        MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Exatamente nesta linha

> toolbarTitle.setText(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante());

quando vou setar o nome do restaurante da a exceção, porque daria isto ?

- Ja observei que os restaurantes as vezes duplicam no resultado da pesquisa.
- O legal é que acontece isto somente quando pesquiso o nome do restaurante, caso contrario ele entra normalmente, então se eu pesquiso ele e entro novamente da problema.

  ANEXOS:

Foto do debug na parte restaurante = (Restaurante) getArguments().getSerializable(RESTAURANTE_CARDAPIO);

[image: foto do debug]

Comment: Certifique-se que você esta ativando o XML correto e que neste XML tenha o objeto com o ID  toolbar_title

Comment: Você está usando Activity ou Fragment?

Comment: Existem algumas hipóteses, mas para confirmar de fato o veredito, você teria que acrescentar mais do seu código na pergunta.

Comment: @LeonardoDias estou utilizando fragment

Comment: @acklay pode me falar que adiciono, o que precisar

Comment: Por exemplo, `restaurante`, não tem em momento algum onde ele está sendo declarado (na pergunta) ou recebendo seu construtor. Isso mesmo pode ser uma causa ao problema.

Comment: Renan, adicionei uma resposta, da uma olhada! Abraços

Comment: @LeonardoDias e no caso da duplicação de restaurante na lista de pesquisa

Comment: Você tem que debugar pra ver se realmente está atribuindo valor ao `restaurante` através do `(Restaurante) getArguments().getSerializable(RESTAURANTE_CARDAPIO);`

Comment: @acklay debuguei e esta chegando normalmente, o problema ta na hora de setar.

Comment: Coloque desta forma: `toolbarTitle.setText(" "+restaurante.getNomeRestaurante())`... e diz o que acontece.

Comment: @acklay do mesmo jeito

Comment: @acklay estava aqui pensando, se eu redirecionar para o fragmento de listagem dos restaurantes, o que acha

Comment: @RenanRodrigues eu queria poder te ajudar, mas não tem como reproduzir seu erro aqui porque o código não está completo, tanto o xml, quanto sua classe. Não entendi muito bem o que seria "redirecionar para o fragmento de listagem dos restaurantes".... As respostas que lhe foram dadas são válidas, porém para alguns casos. Basicamente são respostas que supõe um erro, estão "chutando". Eu poderia chutar alguma coisa, mas são inúmeras possibilidades de erro. =D

Comment: Consegui chegar a algo, verifiquei que o que esta acontecendo é quando pesquiso ele não esta achando null, porém o que acha do geviewbyid é outro valor, estou averiguando aqui ainda

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60141/discussion-between-renan-rodrigues-and-acklay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renan,

O problema está aqui:

```
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Quando você chama o `getActivity()`, você está dizendo pra ele ir procurar no layout da Activity que chamou o seu fragment.

Quando você declara o layout do Fragment, você chama lá no onCreateView assim, por exemplo:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
```

Esse `view` que você deve chamar pra referenciar um item do layout, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Comment: apareceu um problema no `view` falando `cannot resolve symbol view`

Comment: sua alteração não funcionou, na verdade deu mais problemas ainda, todos os restaurantes estao dando o mesmo erro da questão agora. Eu fiz assim: `TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);` tive que usar `getView` por não dar para usar `view`

Answer (score 0):

O erro se dá porque o findViewById() desta linha:

```
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

está retornando null, ou seja, não encontrou uma view com esse id e com isso o app crashea porque você está tentando setar o texto em algo que não existe.

Como você não postou o código vou dar alguns chutes, visto que ele aparenta estar rodando dentro de um Fragment (pelo getActivity que você está chamando):

- Se o seu TextView com o atributo "toolbar_title" estiver no layout da Activity, confira se no layout da mesma o nome está batendo certinho.
- Se o seu TextView com o atributo "toolbar_title" estiver no layout do Fragment, confira se no layout do mesmo o nome está batendo certinho, crie uma variável global no Fragment e use o findViewById() no método OnCreateView() do Fragment.

Exemplo:

```
private TextView mToolBarTitle;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article_detail, container, false);
    mToolbarTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    ...

    return rootView;
}
```

Por fim, sete o texto usando essa variável global no seu método:

```
try{
    updateCarrinho();
    Globales.setListaOpcionais(null);

    mToolbarTitle.setText(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante());
}catch (Exception e){
    MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Ou tentando setar algo que não existem em um local onde tem inserir um texto.